# React Redux - props are undefined while rendering from Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to incorporate ImmutableJS to my React app. So now my reducer looks like this:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'

const initialState = Map({
  data: [],
  sections: []
});

const AppState = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTENT':
      return state.set('data', action.response);
    case 'ADD_SECTION':
      return state.set('sections', [ ...state.get('sections'), action.payload ]);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default AppState;
```

And this is all fine and good. But in my component I have `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const d = state.app.get('data');

  return {
    works: d.works,
    pages: d.pages,
    sections: state.app.get('sections')
  }
};
```

and then I want to display the data:

```
  {
    this.props.works.map(d => {
      return <div>d</div>
    })
  }
```

And I am getting

> TypeError: this.props.works.map is not a function

When I `console.log` instead, I am getting that `this.props.works` is undefined. What can I do?

Comment: Whats in `action.response` and what do you see if you `console.log( state.app.get('data') )`?

Comment: `action.response` is my parsed json file. After `console.logging` I am getting `Map {size: 2...`, so normal ImmutableJS map.

Comment: Ok, And what do you see after `console.log( state.app.get('data').toObject() )`, Is it the correct data `works` and `pages`?

Comment: Interesting, `TypeError: state.app.get(...).toObject is not a function`. But when I view the state in Redux Dev Extension, everything seems in place.

Comment: Sorry, try .toArray()

Comment: Right, I get two `Map`s.

Comment: If you get `Map`, then change `works: d.works` to `works: d.get('works')`

Comment: So obvious! Works like a charm, please post this comment as an answer so I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Immutable JS

In your `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const d = state.app.get('data');

  return {
    works: d.works,
    ...
```

To access data from `d`, change the way you access data, From `d.works` to **`d.get('works')`**

```
  return {
    works: d.get('works'),
    pages: d.get('pages'),
    sections: state.app.get('sections')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling d.works but it is not defined. I think in your action when you pass in your initial state you need to also defined works

```
const initialState = Map({
   data: [
       works: [],
       pages: []
   ],
   sections: []
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but this doesn't help. Actually, you have syntax errors in your code ;)